# How to check if a word is more common in its plural form rather than in it's singular form in an array of words (with Python/NLTK)?

Tags: python, nltk

I'm trying to do the NLTK exercices but I can't do this one. "Which nouns are more common in their plural form, rather than their singular form? (Only consider regular plurals, formed with the -s suffix.)". I spent a day thinking about this and trying things but I just can't get it.
Thank you.

Comment: have you tried anything yet? Step one would certainly be to tokenize the text.

Comment: I took the brown corpus. All the words. They are tokenized and tagged. I took only the nouns, without tags or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a corpus, do a count_:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> texts = brown.words()[:10000]
>>> word_counts = Counter(texts)
>>> word_counts['dollar']
5
>>> word_counts['dollars']
15
```

But do note that sometimes it's unclear when you use only surface strings in counting, e.g.

```
>>> texts = brown.words()[:10000]
>>> word_counts = Counter(texts)
>>> word_counts['hits']
14
>>> word_counts['hit']
34
>>> word_counts['needs']
14
>>> word_counts['need']
30
```

POS sensitive counts (see types vs tokens):

```
>>> texts = brown.tagged_words()[:10000]
>>> word_counts = Counter(texts)
>>> word_counts[('need', 'NN')]
6
>>> word_counts[('needs', 'NNS')]
3
>>> word_counts[('hit', 'NN')]
0
>>> word_counts[('hits', 'NNS')]
0
```

Let's reverse engineer a little, `brown` corpus is nice and it's tokenized and tagged in NLTK but if you want to use your own corpus, then you have to consider the follow:

- Which corpus to use? How to tokenize? How to POS-tag?
- What are you counting? Types or tokens?
- How to handle POS ambiguity? How to differentiate Nouns from non-Nouns?

Finally, consider this:

- Is there really a way to find out whether plural or singular is more common for a word in language? Or will it always be relative to the corpus you chose to analyze?
- Are there cases where plural or singular don't exists for certain nouns? (Most probably the answer is yes).

Comment: Yes. I'd use the brown corpus. And you do this manually with single words. But, how to do generally with all brown corpus words, for example? In an automatic way.

Comment: I can do it with a loop. But, is there any special and magical NLTK function that does this?

Comment: So I need a loop that checks for every single word if there's the same word ending in s or something. Right. I'll try it and add to this as a response. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*brw* is an array of words.

```
counter = Counter(brw);
plurals = [];
for word in brw:
    if(word[-1]!='s'):
        plural = counter[word+'s'];
        singul = counter[word];
        if(plural>singul):
            plurals.append(word+'s');
```

*plurals* is the output array, only with plurals (repeated, meh). If I use set(), they wont be repeated. Is this right?